# LINQ GroupJoin to IGrouping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Imagine I have two Entities in my EF DataContext:

```
class Person
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  ...
}

class Address
{
  int PersonId { get; set; }
  string EMail { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

There are no navigational properties (and I don't want to introduce any) so I use a `GroupJoin` to get a range of People with their addresses.

So I'm doing:

```
var result = context.Set<Person>()
                    .GroupJoin(context.Set<Address>(),
                      x => x.Id,
                      x => x.PersonId, (person, addresses) =>
                      new { Person = person, Addresses = addresses.DefaultIfEmpty() });
```

The `result` is currently of type `IQueryable<'a>`, where `'a` is `new { Person, IEnumerable<Address> }`.

Now I can't figure out how to transform this so that I'd get a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Person, Address>>` as a result. From my understanding, this is basically the same kind of structure.

Comment: context.Set<Person>()
   . ...
   .GroupBy(x => x.Person, x => x.Addresses)

Comment: @schglurps That would give you `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Person, IEnumerable<Address>>` :)

Comment: Is there a reason you need it to be specifically `IGrouping`? Your result data will already be in the format of `[{ Person: Thomas, Address = [ Address1, Address2 ]}, { Person: Rob, Address = [ Address3 ] }]`, which is essentially grouped, but simply not an `IGrouping`.

Comment: @Rob yes, I want to declare a method for further processing, e.g. `GetPeopleWithAddresses(...)` but the current result is an anonymous type not following any Interface so I can't define any return Type. I could create a Type `PersonWithAddresses` but It seems redundant to me and I have many similar constellations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is a replacement of the anonymous type in order to be able to define a function result, you can use your own generic class for that, for instance

```
public class Grouping<TKey, TELement>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TELement> Elements { get; set; }
}

var result = context.Set<Person>()
    .GroupJoin(context.Set<Address>(), x => x.Id, x => x.PersonId,
        (person, addresses) => new Grouping<Person, Address>
        {
            Key = person,
            Elements = addresses.DefaultIfEmpty()
        });
```

The type of the result is `IQueryable<Grouping<Person, Address>>` and can be used to further apply `Where`, `OrderBy` etc.

**Important:** Do not try to implement `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` (or `IEnumerable<T>` in general) in your type - EF doesn't like that and will throw a runtime exception. Also do not use constructor or factory helpers like `Tuple.Create`. Simple property get/set, nothing else (like in entity classes). Of course you can call the class and its members whatever you like.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of mistake I did. I had a class exactly like in your example except for the Fact it was also implementing `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` because I already used that here and there and had some Extension Methods etc. The moment you implement that Interface, even if it just has two simple method overrides which should not matter at all, it fails. Thank you!

Comment: @thomasjaworski.com Well, you are not the only one :-) It's the most logical step that everyone will do (I did it too:-)), I have no idea why they put that constraint. Anyway, as usual, trial and error method works. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the nicest way you're going to be able to do it is:

```
public class Grouping<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    private IEnumerable<TElement> collection;
    public Grouping(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> collection)
    {
        Key = key;
        this.collection = collection;
    }
    public TKey Key
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return collection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var result = context.Set<Person>()
                    .GroupJoin(context.Set<Address>(),
                      x => x.Id,
                      x => x.PersonId, (person, addresses) =>
                      new Grouping<Person, Address>(person, addresses.DefaultIfEmpty() });

//Return type can be defined as IEnumerable<IGrouping<Person, Address>>
```

^ Note, this was not tried with EntityFramework. You may need to keep your anonymous object, call `ToList`, and then select the new `Grouping` types.

Alternatively, you could use `Join` instead of `GroupJoin`. This will give you a row per address (even if it's the same person), which you can then use @schglurps suggestion of `.GroupBy()`

So:

```
context.Set<Person>()
                    .Join(context.Set<Address>(),
                      x => x.Id,
                      x => x.PersonId, (person, addresses) =>
                      new { Person = person, Addresses = addresses.DefaultIfEmpty() })
                      .GroupBy(x => x.Person, x => x.Addresses);
```

*However*, if a person has *no addresses*, it will not appear in the result collection. If that's fine, this solution is a lot more succinct.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Interestingly, I was working on a very similar approach while waiting for some response. As you pointed out, EntityFramework is not delighted ;) (`NotSupportedException: A type that implements IEnumerable 'MyProject.Grouping'2[[MyProject.Context.Person, ...],[MyProject.Context.Address, ...]]' cannot be initialized in a LINQ to Entities query.`)

I was planning to put that method in my DAL for further processing, the early execution when using ToList() would be a huge drawback. Still, interesting approach.